# How to define a type which 'set-cookie' is `string[]` but any other keys are `string`, in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to define a type which is like response headers, which is like:

```
type Headers = { [key: string]: string }
```

but if the key is `set-cookie`, its type should be `string[]`.

I tried

```
type Headers = { 'set-cookie'?: string[] } & { [key: string]: string };
```

but for code:

```
const headers: H = {
  'set-cookie': ['cookie'],
  'aaa': '111'
}
```

it has compilation errors:

```
TS2322: Type '{ 'set-cookie': string[]; aaa: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Headers'.   
Type '{ 'set-cookie': string[]; aaa: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.     
Property ''set-cookie'' is incompatible with index signature.       
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Is it possible to define such a typing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks but a little sad to know the answer :(

Comment: Me too; my only suggestion is that everyone who feels like this should be possible should go to [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) and give it a  and possibly explain why it's important for their use case.  If more people want a feature and can make a strong argument why having it improves the language then there's more of a chance of it being implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Headers` type should be an intersection of two types.

```
interface CookieHeader {'set-cookie'?: string[]; }
```

Defines the `set-cookie` key to a type `string[]`, also optional (`?`), since your `Headers` object may not have this property.

The second definition is quite more complex

```
type CommonHeaders = { [key: string]: string } & { 'set-cookie'?: never };
```

This is literally defining an interface of `string` keys without a `set-cookie` key.
Take a look to the [Typescript utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html).

Then, the `Headers` type definition is easy

```
type Headers = CookieHeader | CommonHeaders;

const headers1: Headers = {
    key1: `value1`,
    key2: `value2`,
    'set-cookie': [`prop1`, `prop2`]
}; // Good

const headers2: Headers = {
    key1: `value1`,
    key2: `value2`
}; // Still good

const headers3: Headers = {
    key1: `value1`,
    key2: `value2`,
    'set-cookie': `prop1`
}; // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, but I have a question about the `CommonHeaders`, seems we have to use `any` as the type of keys to make it work? So other keys can be non-strings, like `key1: 123`

Comment: Seems like you misused `Exclude`, its definition is `type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T`, so your `Headers` is actually `CookieHeader & {[key: string]: any; }`

Comment: You are right, let me change the answer, (:

Comment: Done. With the change, the `Headers` type must be the union of `CookieHeader` or `CommonHeaders`. If stays as the intersection, `set-cookies` would have to be `string[] & never` which is resolved as `never`.

Comment: Still doesn't work if you set `set-cookies` with any other keys. `headers1` and `headers3` has compilation errors in my side (typescript 3.8.3)

Comment: Have you changed the `Headers` declaration from intersection to union? `type Headers = CookieHeader | CommonHeaders;`

Comment: Yes, please see <https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHt0GtgQBIRwAm0yA3gOQDOEYAtApjhBQPwBcyVYUoA5gG0AugG5kAXwBQYAJ4AHFBgC2S9CALFoVZAF5yyAVggzO3XiD5DTPfhOQAyfdVoMmuNpxAQAbqXEjJaXkUAFkZDRIobT0MbFwI0gAfNHQVNQSogMlGEG5kAAtCSKoARk4wjOjySWRa5CMZMuQAA284ABsAVwgS5oAaGrqGgCZOVo7u4f7B2ud6RjiWTgFmuSh0OV6+lrWNqaFJf2QAemPkAHFMIkCcvMLNKNHkCqKtXWq6+uMm8a6e6c+IzGbT+U0OYlOyAAymBgO12sg+Fcbmo7q8ogBmcrhdFVMgzL6NYETf4DQHGJ6-SYAupzVyLChjXabZrgk5nAAqwWQ1BsFgoyGA2hA6DAyDgVCowD4IDgACN2igwOhkLIFDyzPxhBQAHRAA>

Comment: I am trying to figure out what is wrong. It must be something related to the tsconfig, because it is working perfectly for me...